# Permission errors on deployment of Elastic Beanstalk Worker Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

A few weeks ago I shut down my elastic beanstalk application that had been working fine for months. I now want to add it again, so I create a new Elastic Beanstalk Application and I deploy the same deployment that was deployed and worked for months earlier.

Instead of just working like before, I run into a lot of issues such as:

- Your requirements.txt file is invalid.
- Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module.
- ImportError: no module name pymysql
- error: could not create '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask': Permission denied

I have searched for solutions for all of these problems, and all of them seem to be connected to issues with permissions of the user. But I'm not sure what is wrong with my permissions.

My Elastic Beanstalk Application is set to the ec2-role. The ec2-role have the "AdministratorAccess" Policy, which should let the user do whatever they want. I have also set AdministratorAccess to the only IAM User and the only IAM Group I got.

I have played around with some sudo commands in ssh and that seems to work. For example, when I deploy my application I get the "Your requirements.txt file is invalid", however if I do `sudo pip install -r requirements.txt` it succeeds, same with Flask installation.

So question is: Is this permission errors? If so, what could be wrong with my permissions? Shouldnt AdministratorAccess open up all permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following way, I'm not sure if there actually was permission errors or not and exactly what was the root of the issue. But it helped:

- I replaced PIL in my requirements.txt with Pillow.
- I added 2 Custom Policies to my ec2-role. The policies can be found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.roles.aeb.html, however I still left "AdministratorAccess" on the ec2-role. In my head this makes 0 sense because AdministratorAccess should already give the user the same permissions as those custom policies(?), but it worked.